# I want to get values in List EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have table i am using two foreign key of different table every time i insert value one of them will be null. I want to get the record in List using EF it gives me the following error

> The cast to value type 'System.Int64' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Here is my Code

```
public static List<ShowCartModelView> ViewAllCarts()
    {
        try
        {
            var userid = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];
            var id = (long)userid;
            using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                var model =
                    db.Carts
                        .Where(x => x.memberId == id)
                        .Select(x => new ShowCartModelView
                        {
                            CardId = x.CardId,
                            ProductId = x.ProductId,
                            AccountType = x.UserDumps.accountType,
                            DumpsCountry = x.UserDumps.country,
                            CardsCountry = x.UserCards.country,
                            CardName = x.UserCards.name,
                            CardsBin = x.UserCards.nummber,
                            DumpsBin = x.UserDumps.bin,
                            DumpsBank = x.UserDumps.Bank,
                            DumpsPrice = x.UserDumps.price,
                            CardsPrice = x.UserCards.Price,
                            CartType = x.CartType

                        }).ToList();

                return model;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I want to show record in list view Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity has an Int64 or long defined while the respective column is nullable, change the datatype to: `long?`

Comment: I have kept it nullable in both table and also in ShowCartModelView

Comment: In the table and the ModelView, yes, but what about the Cart entity?

Comment: In cart entity i have also put it nullable

Comment: var userid = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];
            var id = (long)userid;  Maybe this Id is null?

Comment: i have solved it thank you so much for your response. It show me the way.